# Equivalent of boost xml (nvp) serialization in java

Tags: java, c++, xml, serialization

I am moving from C++ to Java, and I am used to the way boost serialization works for xml. What is very good with it is:

1. that I only have to write one function that is used for both parsing and generating the XML. This function is basically a mapping between the field value and the name of the xml tag.
2. that the XML generated is light weight, and only contain the information we want to save (no information about the type of the field, the name of the class...)

I am looking for something that would have the same advantages, in JAVA. Here is a C++ example:

```
  struct ContractDefinition
    : public fme::ToStringInterface
  {
  public:
    std::string name;

    template<class archive>
    void serialize(archive& ar, const unsigned int FME_UNUSED(version))
    {
      using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
      ar & make_nvp< std::string >("name", name);
    }    
  };
```

and the result looks like that:

```
<name>WHATEVER THE NAME IS</name>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [jaxb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html).

Comment: @jules, cool, finding the right thing (that already exists) is the hardest part of working in Java.. :)